# How to animate the background color of a scene view (SCNView). Note, not a scene (SCNScene), or conventional UIView

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnview

Is it possible to animate the `.backgroundColor` property of an `SCNView`?

Please note, it is easy to animate the background of an actual scene (`SCNScene`) and I know how to do that.  It is also easy to animate the background of a conventional `UIView`.

I've not been able to figure out how to animate the `.backgroundColor` property of an `SCNView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you take the default SceneKit Game Template (the one with the rotating Jet) I got it working by doing this:

Here is my `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene() // SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
    
    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = .omni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    
    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
    
    // retrieve the ship node
    // let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
    
    // animate the 3d object
    // ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))
    
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    
    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene
    
    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    
    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = true
    
    // Configure the initial background color of the SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    
    // Setup a SCNAction that rotates i.Ex the HUE Value of the Background
    let animColor = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 10.0) { _ , timeElapsed in
        
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hue: timeElapsed/10, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }

    // Run the Action (here using the rootNode)
    scene.rootNode.runAction(animColor)
    
    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

This might not be the best solution, but using a SCNTransaction I had no luck. Hope I could help in some way.

Comment: Huh.  So just TBC, that "actually works" for you ?!  If so, thanks a million.  I wonder WTF I am doing wrong?

Comment: here is my project, feel free to give it a try: https://drive.google.com/file/d/131KMZbZqHODwkcVPuVo-hCqeL2E5vtmV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to the amazing & correct answer of @ZAY.

You have to do a frame-by-frame animation of the color and,

For some reason,

1. You do the action on the **scene view**
2. But. You run the action on the **root node of the scene**.

So, it's a miracle.

Works perfectly.